# Ubuntu Netboot - PXE can't find kernel 'linux'

Tags: server, 18.04, pxe

I just set up my PXE Server on Lubuntu, everything is running good so far.. PXE detects my DHCP Server, menu shows up, but when I select one of the entrys, for example the one that leads to ubuntu-installer, it shows the errormessage 'loading /ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux failed no such file or directory' I've tried nearly everything from moving 'linux' into another folder to chmod 777 my tftp root folder. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score -1):

Just download the linux file inside the ubuntu-installer (link)  and replace the bad linux file ( tftpboot/bionic64/ubuntu-installer/amd64.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/

That work for me !